# How do I apply for a permission to stay for a child born in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, children, dependent-visa

I live in the UK on a Tier 2 visa, and my son was born in the UK. According to https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/family-members:

> If you have children while you’re in the UK, you can apply for permission for them to stay.
>
> You must do this if you want to travel in and out of the UK with your child.
>
> When you apply you must send a full UK birth certificate showing the names of both of your child’s parents.

Is this permission to stay the same as a Tier 2 visa? Also, where do I apply for this permission and where do I send the birth certificate to?

Comment: [This page](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-child) might be the right one...maybe.

Comment: See also  http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-a-new-visitor-visa-to-the-uk-from-within-the-uk/6174#6174

Comment: Is the other parent a British citizen or have indefinite leave to remain?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, no, we are not British citizens nor do we have indefinite leaves to remain.

Comment: In that case I think @mkennedy has provided the right link.